# Reference request for convex geometry?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for a reference for an elementary convex geometry.
In Appendix A (page 1810) of [this paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v171-n3-p08-s.pdf) by Green and Tao, they cover some basic results from elementary convex geometry. The results seem straight forward enough, and I kinda get the proof, but since I know nothing about convex geometry I wanted to have a reference so that I can learn the terminologies and understand the proof properly. I don't know where to begin with finding the literature in this subject.... Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_geometry gives Expository articles on convex geometry

K. Ball, An elementary introduction to modern convex geometry, in: Flavors of Geometry, pp. 1–58, Math. Sci. Res. Inst. Publ. Vol. 31, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1997, available online.
M. Berger, Convexity, Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol. 97 (1990), 650—678. DOI: 10.2307/2324573
P. M. Gruber, Aspects of convexity and its applications, Exposition. Math., Vol. 2 (1984), 47—83.
V. Klee, What is a convex set? Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol. 78 (1971), 616—631, DOI: 10.2307/2316569
and also a list of books

Comment: So, how's it going?

Comment: Your references were very helpful, thank you!